# trouble resetting form through javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp, validation

I have the below jQuery function which is called when ever I click a button on my page. This button is supposed to reset the form and reload a fresh page.

```
function Create(txt) {
    if (txt="createUser") {
        document.forms[0].reset();
        $('#myform').each(function() {
            this.reset();
        });
        $('input[name=method]').val(txt);
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
}
```

But for some reason, it does not go to `this.reset()` at all and I see all the form values in my action class.  How should I solve this?

Below is how the button is defined.

```
<input type="button" value="Create" class="btn" onclick="Create('createUser');">
```

edit: Ok guys.. i know how input type="reset" works and i have another button in my page doing the same.. I have a create user form where i can search and see an existing user details or fill the form and create a new user. if i search for a user and then click on create to create another user, it sends a new request to the server and reloads the page.. but in the action class.. the bean has not been reset.. and i get all the values back on the page. hence ..i want to reset the form...without using the reset button...

I selected John's answer .. made a slight modification and below is the final function i used.

```
function Create(txt){
if (txt="createUser"){
var $form = $('#myform');
    $form.find(':input').not(':button,:submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected'); // Clear all inputs
    $form.find('input[name=method]').val(txt);
    $form.submit();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code for your form?

Comment: Also, a few things to fix in your code:  1) change `if (txt="createUser") {` to `if (txt === "createUser") {`, so that it is actually doing the comparison (not assigning a value to the `txt` variable), 2) The way that you would call `.reset()` with jQuery is `$('#myform')[0].reset();` . . . a) you are using an `id` selector, so there will only be one element returned (no need for `.each()`) and b) `.reset()` is a JS method, not a jQuery method, so you need to run it on the DOM reference (`$('#myform')[0]`), not the jQuery object, and 3) for jQuery, `this` needs to be formatted like: `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you have `=` where you should have `==`, but that means the if-statement is always true. It is not, however, the reason you "see all the form values in my action class".

I think the problem may be that you are misinterpreting what the `reset()` method does. It does not clear all the input values; instead, it resets them to their original values (i.e., the values in the "value" attributes).

You may want to clear them yourself, rather than use the `reset()` method.

```
function Create(txt) {
    if (txt == 'createUser') {
        var $form = $('#myform');

        // Clear form values
        $form.find(':input:not(:button,:submit,:reset,:checkbox,:radio,:hidden)').val('');
        $form.find('input:checkbox,input:radio)').prop('checked', false);

        $form.find('input[name=method]').val(txt);
        $form.submit();
    }
}
```

Note: The [`:input` selector](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) matches all input, textarea, select and button elements.

Note: It appears the OP does not want hidden inputs to be cleared, but does want checkboxes and radio buttons cleared.

Comment: I think you should provide code for cleaning selects and textareas as well if OP has some of them in the form.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi - The `':input'` selector matches selects and textareas too. You may have thought I just had `'input'`. I modified my answer though to use `':input:not(:button)`' because the `':input'` selector matches buttons too, and I don't think the OP wants those cleared.

Comment: Exactly, perfect answer.

Comment: @DJR - I modified my answer to match what I think you want. I think it is better to use `.prop()` instead of `removeAttr()`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of java script, you can have html code,

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting a variable here -

```
if (txt="createUser"){...
```

Change it to -

```
if (txt == "createUser") {..
```

That way you're doing a comparison, instead of setting a variable.

Comment: While it definitely needs to be fixed, the `if` will evaluate the assignment as `true` and enter into the code in the `if` block, so that's not what is stopping his form from resetting.

Answer (score 0):

the button does not have type="reset" so either change it to reset or use

`document.getElementById("myform").reset();` instead of

```
document.forms[0].reset();
$('#myform').each(function(){
          this.reset();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#createUserButton").on("click", function() {
        var form = $("#myForm")[0];
        form.reset();
        $("input[name=method]").val("CreateUser");
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

And your button becomes:

```
<input type="button" value="Create" class="btn" id="createUserButton">
```

I'd suggest you to place an id attribute as well in your input text, something like:

```
<input type="text" name="method" id="methodName" />
```

And then you could reference it by id which is faster than by name, like this:

```
$("#methodName").val("CreateUser");
```

Your code was wrong, in your if you should've used `==` or `===` instead of just `=` and your form should've just have called `reset` method. No need to iterate over an id using `each`, even because an ID have to be unique in an HTML page.

Here's a workin [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/9Trmf/), just type something in the first input to see it happening.